# Parametrization and Extrema for Multivariable Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

We are given the function:

$$f(x,y)=x^2+xy+x+y^2$$

On the set $S=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 \leq 9\}$

I found the critical point on the interior of $S$ to be $(-2/3,1/3)$.

I am asked to parametrize the boundary of $S$ in terms of theta using sine and cosine, and write $f$ in terms of theta on the boundary. (don't forget restrictions on theta).

I'm not sure how to do this.

After we do that, we are asked to find the extrema of $f$ on $S$. I am also not sure how to do this.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!